# Connecting to SOAP server with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am new to Soap and WSDLs. I am trying to replicate this example transaction using Soap in PHP.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://example.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <open:processEvent>
     <authenticationToken>
        <userName>1</userName>
        <password>password1234</password>
     </authenticationToken>
     <sourceThirdPartyId>1</sourceThirdPartyId>
     <dealerEndpointId>4</dealerEndpointId>
     <eventType>GetAdvisorConfig</eventType>
     <payload></payload>
     <payloadVersion>STAR-5.5.4</payloadVersion>
  </open:processEvent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So far I am able to make a connection to the soap server, but am unsure how to insert the required variables.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://example.com?wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => 1 ));

echo("\nDumping client object functions:\n");
   var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());

$response = $soapClient->__soapCall("processEvent",array("processEvent"=>"GetAdvisorConfig"));
echo("\nReturning value of __soapCall() call: ".$response);
```

Comment: Normally the required values are supplied as a multidimensional array that mimics the XML of the body. This array is provided as the second argument for __soapCall(). What kind of data goes in the payload?

Comment: The payload is not used when receiving data. I am going to try to send it as raw XML using NuSOAP.